# Upon the serialization of an object does the reference stay or create a new object?

Tags: java, object, serialization, save

This might sound like an obvious question, but I'm wondering whether serialization causes an object which refers to another to just become a copy instead of a reference.

If I'm being unclear, consider this code:

```
public class Test implements Serializable {
    String thing1 = new String("test");
    String thing2 = thing1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Blah blah implementation
    }
    public static void serialize() {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileoutput = new FileOutputStream(new File("test.ser"));
            ObjectOutputStream objectoutput = new ObjectOutputStream(fileoutput);
            objectoutput.writeObject(thing2);
            objectoutput.close();
            fileoutput.close();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When deserialized, will it return as a reference to thing1 or will it just be a copy, but not referenced to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really no way that  a serialized thing2 could retain a reference to thing1. This is because the process of serialization turns thing2 into a byte stream representing the state and contents of an object of the class  that thing2 is an instance of. If the object contains other  objects they too must be serializable for serialization to not fail. And their state is in turn serialized.

But the specific memory addresses of the object and its contents at the time it was serialized are not retained. After all a serialized object  can be written to a file that persists after the program that serialized it ceases to execute.

And deserialization in turn turns the byte stream back into into a copy of that class instance with that serialized state.

So no, it will just be a copy on deserialization and won't retain reference to another object of the same type it was copied from.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer but it should be easy to test. Deserialize and test for ==, if the result is true than it is the exact same instance.

If the strings are not the same instance then == will be false, while equals will be true.